# Dynamic type checking in PHP

Tags: php, types, casting

I'm writing some code in PHP, and I'd like to do something a little different if the variable is a string, or an instance of a certain class (or derived!), but the only casting I could find references for online performs an explicit static cast, rather than a dynamic cast. Is it possible to check the type of a given variable at runtime and compare it?

Comment: Do you have such case in real - a variable that may contain both string and object?

Comment: You mean like the `is_()` functions? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Be careful because some libraries like PDO will instantiate objects of type `stdClass`. Duck typing might be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php is what you are looking for.
For checking if a variable is from given instance - http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php

Comment: Just read the warning on the manual page. Use the `is_*()` functions. Additional you should use the `instanceof` language construct instead of the `is_a()`-function http://php.net/language.operators.type

Answer (score 2):

The PHP [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php) recommends using the `is_*()` function where `*` is a type. That should get the effects you want, as long as you know what types to check for.

Of course if you provide more details about what you are trying to do I can try to give a specific example.